# How to bound non-linear terms of integral operator in Sobolev Space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, frechet-derivative

Let $I=[0,1]$ and consider the function $F:H^1(I)\to \mathbb R$ given by $$F(u)=\int_I \bigr( u(t) \bigr)^4 dt. $$
This makes sense, because $H^1(I)\hookrightarrow C^0(I).$ I want to understand the Fréchet derivate $dF(u)[\phi]$ for $\phi\in H^1(I)$. To do so, I consider
\begin{align}
F(u+\phi)=\int_Iu^4 +4\int_I u^3\phi +6\int_I u^2\phi^2 + 4\int_I u\phi^3+\int_I\phi^4,
\end{align}
Clearly, the linear term should be $L_u(\phi):=4\int_I u^3\phi$; however when I want to prove it, I need to show that \begin{align}
\lim_{\Vert\phi\Vert_{H^1}\to 0}\frac{\left\vert 6\int_I u^2\phi^2 + 4\int_I u\phi^3+\int_I\phi^4\right \vert}{\Vert \phi \Vert_{H^1}}=0.
\end{align}
However, I need to bound these integrals with the $H^1$ norm, but I have unsuccesful to do so. Are there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just pull out copies of $\|\phi\|_{L^\infty} \le C \|\phi \|_{H^1}$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor do you know a reference for this inequality? This is exactly what I need

Comment: Well this is precisely the continuity of the embedding $H^1(I) \hookrightarrow C^0(I)$ that you quoted. In fact you get Holder continuity, which comes from Morrey's inequality (I believe Brezis has the result for 1D)